# How to populate text / formula field based on permission set group assigned?

Tags: apex

Can you please let me know on how to populate text field on user record based on permission set groups assigned to the user ?

Comment: I tried using formuma field and custom permission. It is not working ? Only trigger is the option ?

IF( $Permission.custom_permission1, "usertype-1", IF( $Permission.custom_permission2 , "usertype-2","Default"))

Comment: @sfdcfox can you please help on this ?